# Simple Way for Modifying Attributes of Single nodes in Networkx 2.1+

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

I'm looking for an simple way of modifying the value of a single attribute of a single node inside a NetworkX Graph.

The NetworkX documentation only mentions a function for setting an attribute for all nodes in the graph, e.g.:

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, bb, 'betweenness')
```

This might be appropriate in many situations in which such such an attribute is easy to calculate for all nodes in a graph (like be mentioned betweenness). Likewise, there is an easy way to access single node attributes in NetworkX:

```
graph.nodes[nodeName][attribute]
```

However, the attributes accessed this way are read-only.

So what i'm looking for a way to set attributes as simple as reading.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient" ? Fast ?

Comment: Sorry, i may have clarified that in advance. I simply mean with writing less code (less then e.g. gather the attributes of all nodes in a dict, modify the only attribute i actually want to modify and then call the mentioned setter ).

Comment: Ok, then you could improve your question by showing us the few lines that you currently use to modify a single attribute.

Comment: Actually, i haven't implemented is this way yet. It's just one way it should work w.r.t. the set_node_attributes function as described in the documentation. But i will alter the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your example, `bb` is a dict whose keys are the nodes.  You don't need the dict to have a key for all nodes in the graph, just the nodes for which you want to define the attribute.  In the example below, I create a graph, and then set the `'weight'` of node `0` to be `5` and of node `3` to be `2`.  This leaves the attributes for the other nodes unaffected, so since they've never been created, they don't exist.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(10,0.2)
nx.set_node_attributes(G, {0:5, 3:2}, 'weight')
G.nodes[0]['weight']
> 5
G.nodes[3]['weight']
> 2
G.nodes[1]['weight']
> KeyError: 'weight'
```

So we set the weight for `0` and `3` but not any of the others.  You could also set more than one attribute at once, but that requires a slightly different call.  Here we have

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, {1:{'weight':-1, 'volume':4}})
G.nodes[1]['weight']
> -1
G.nodes[1]['volume']
> 4
```

Just to see what the attributes look like after all of that:

```
G.nodes(data=True)
> NodeDataView({0: {'weight': 5}, 1: {'weight': -1, 'volume': 4}, 2: {}, 3: {'weight': 2}, 4: {}, 5: {}, 6: {}, 7: {}, 8: {}, 9: {}})
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, solves the problem for me